# which version of a gem is installed when requiring a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using the thumbs_up gem and on [github](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up/) there's a `master` branch (0.4.6) and an `engine` branch (0.3.2). When I require the gem in my `Gemfile` with

```
gem 'thumbs_up'
```

I see that version 0.4.6 was installed. I verify this is the right version running in my dev environment by doing `bundle exec gem which thumbs_up` and when I look at the `VERSION` file I see it's 0.4.6.

So when I look at the code I'm expecting to find an `unvote_for` method but it doesn't have one. Instead it has one called `clear_votes`. Now I'm confused because `clear_votes` is supposed to be in version 0.3.2 but as far as I can tell, I'm on version 0.4.6.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the gem used is the latest available when running 'bundle install'. You can specify a version (or version constraints) in the Gemfile. To update the version of the gem used, you have to run `bundle update <gemname>`, and it will do so according to your gemfile.

About your problem : ensure that your server/console command is prefixed with `bundle exec`. You check also which versions of thumbs_up are installer on your system, and remove the version you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You use Bundler so you can know which version of you gem is using in your Gemfile.lock. Bundler have and use only one version by gem.